# 2003 migrated to new domain - FTP authenticating old domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp, domain, migration

We have a Windows 2003 server we migrated from an old (but still active) domain, to a new domain in a new forest.  There have been no problems with this machine except for something we noticed recently.  Users that access the FTP service on this machine have to provide their OldDomain credentials.

- There are no local users on the server
- The FTP folder Sharing is set to Everyone Everything (we share the folder out too)
- The FTP folder Security has ACL restrictions, namely **OldDomain\Domain Users** and **NewDomain\Domain Users**
- The FTP site is set to allow Anonymous Connections (although when you connect it asks for credentials)

Comment: how did you migrate? is there trust relationship to the old domain? sidhistory?

Comment: Migration was done using ADMT.  There is a full trust.  See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end.  In all pre-2008 versions of IIS, it seems that the authenticating domain is stored in some arcane location.  In order to change this setting, you need to use the ADSUtil command as so:

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>adsutil.vbs set msftpsvc/defaultlogondomain "NewDomain.loc"

defaultlogondomain              : (STRING) "NewDomain.loc"
```